# Gtk-WARNING with display when using sudo in nx

Tags: linux, display, sudo, gtk, nx

I am using nxclient on my Windows machine to connect to a Linux server which is running RHE. I am able to run all programs with GUI correctly. However, when I run the same programs with sudo, I get the following

```
error:(SciTE:25243): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: :1066.0
```

There is no display connected to this machine, so I am gussing nx is setting my $DISPLAY to :1066.0?

Answer (score 0):

problem is that sudo changes you user context to root and root doesn't have a display set.  try using kdesu (for kde) or beesu (for gnome) to launch your app

Comment: Isn't beesu a wrapper around su? I was hoping to find a way that I can use sudo rather than using beesu and entering the root password.

Comment: What happens if you launch sudo with :1066 as a parameter?

Comment: I don't think that's a valid argument: sudo :1066.0 SciTE
sudo: :1066.0: command not found

Comment: how about sudo Scite :1066?